# Gradle get wrong JAVA_HOME value

Tags: ionic-framework, windows-10, capacitor, java-home

I try to run "ionic capacitor run". It is an Ionic 5 Capacitor proejct.

Java installed in c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311 and c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311.

When I set JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin I have got this error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin
[capacitor]         Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
[capacitor]         location of your Java installation.
```

When I set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311 (without \bin suffix) I have got this error:

```
[capacitor]         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         Supplied javaHome must be a valid directory. You supplied: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2
```

The 1.16 version was installed earlier but I uninstalled and installed 1.17.
Finally I end up with 1.8 because I have got an Ionic 4 cordova project which not work with Java 1.17.

I uninstalled/reinstalled Java, set environment variables in users and/or system settings and restarted windows several times, but I still don't know where this C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2 value come from.

My Ionic4 (cordova) project works fine, can find the right value of JAVA_HOME and can build the app.

Answer (score 0):

First start with `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%` , to see what your current Java JDK is set too in the environment and the path.

When setting the environment value use `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311` don't add the \bin that you include in the path, Set the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin` or `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`, Start with the first one to test.

! Important referring to the path on System variables ,Don't confuse it for the User variables path

Once you have changed the values for both environment value and path save and apply, open a new terminal for the new changes to take effect , Then run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%` again if correct.

Comment: echo %JAVA_HOME% show C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311. What is also interesting that the second error mention javaHome not JAVA_HOME